# Showing that the set of functions in $C(I)$ which are monotone on some nontrivial subinterval of $I$ is of first category in $C(I)$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $I = [0,1]$ and let $C(I)$ be the metric space of continuous functions on $I$ with the $L^{\infty}$ norm. I am trying to show that the set of functions in $C(I)$ which are monotone on some nontrivial subinterval of $I$ is of first category in $C(I)$.

I believe that this means that a ‘generic’ continuous function on $[0,1]$ is not monotone on any nontrivial subinterval.

I'd like to use the Baire Category Theorem, but frustratingly am running into troubles with it. Is the Baire Category Theorem the right approach? Is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you do want to use Baire Category. Here's a hint: Start by fixing an interval $[a,b]\subset [0,1]$. What can you say about the subset of those $f\in C(I)$ that are monotone on $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can you say about the subset $C_{r,s}^{+}(I)$ of $C(I)$ consisting of functions which are non-decreasing on $[r,s]\subseteq I$?

Comment: What did this contribute that my comment did not?

Comment: @TedShifrin You can totally make your comment an answer. =)

Comment: Did you look at Ted's comment before posting this T.A.E.?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: I was editing, and had much more, but decided to turn it into a hint, probably before you posted. So we crossed.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: No I did not.

Comment: By the way, you probably do need to separate out non-decreasing and non-increasing as separate sets, which is something Ted did not mention.